# mule custom transformer works in studio, but not deployed to standalone server

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a flow with a custom transformer.  This flow works when I run it under Mule Studio, but fails when run by the mule standalone server. The error message is "No class for element custom-transfomer(name=Update Table)"

```
<flow name="updates" doc:name="updates">

    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="JMSConnector"
        doc:name="JMS" topic="updates" />
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter" />
    <custom-transformer class="com.domain.UpdateTable"
        doc:name="Update Table">
        <spring:property name="table" ref="table" />
    </custom-transformer>

</flow>
```

I also found a [similar question in the old mule forum](http://forums.mulesoft.org/thread.jspa?threadID=6912), but it had no answer;

Comment: Is the `com.domain.UpdateTable` class in the classpath of your application deployed to Muls Standalone?

Comment: The class is within the MuleStudio exported .ZIP, under the classes folder.  It ends up in  $MULE_HOME/apps/myapp/classes/com/domain/UpdateTable.class.  I assume Mule is picking these up as part of the hot deployment - unless there is some project configuration that needs to be done in MuleStudio prior to doing the export?

Comment: Wrt/ my previous comment. I have another class in the same package - the Table itself - which I instantiate as a spring bean (not using a factory), and which is passed as a property to the custom transformer. I would expect that if Spring found that class, UpdateTable should also be available.

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's failing because in theory, with the info you're providing, it should work. Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: We finally determined this was a static initialization error in the class - which was causing a NoClassDefFoundError that mule transformed into "No class for element" - by catching and printing a stacktrace to console.  We further narrowed that down to a [bug in xml-apis-1.3.04.jar](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6205431). The solution was to move that jar from mule/lib/endorsed to mule/lib/user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, which Mule catches and converts into  the "No class for element" message.  Here's a [good description of NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/841299). In my case the error was caused by an exception thrown from a static initializer.